# Secure image Urls

Tags: amazon-web-services, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-storage

I am making a app that allows users to upload images to their profile page. I was using firebase Storage to store the images using a folder for each user. The problem I have is the Url for the images are accessible without evening signing into my app.  Can I limit access to users that have signed in to my app? Im using a custom sign in token. Or do I need to switch to another storage provider.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're using Firebase Storage's **download URLs**. These are (by definition) URLs that give anyone who has them read-only access to the file. Download URLs are only generated when you call `getDownloadUrl()` (or the equivalent method on the platform you use). So if you don't want this behavior, don't call `getDownloadUrl()`.

If you don't have a download URL, the files in Storage are only available by using the Firebase SDK. At that point all access to the files is secured through the security rules that you've defined for your project. For more on this, see the Firebase documentation on [securing access to files](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security).